# Issue while configuring thinking-sphinx, ThinkingSphinx::NoIndicesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm running a ubuntu server with `searchd` which is running after it created index.

So basically all works:

```
indexing index 'pois'...
WARNING: attribute 'id' not found - IGNORING
collected 1760907 docs, 27.4 MB
sorted 3.4 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 1760907 docs, 27438485 bytes
total 2.795 sec, 9813909 bytes/sec, 629822.77 docs/sec
total 1761030 reads, 0.347 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 334 writes, 0.072 sec, 621.5 kb/call avg, 0.2 msec/call avg
ubuntu@stl-back-3:/etc/sphinxsearch$ sudo searchd
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on 127.0.0.1:9312
listening on 127.0.0.1:9306
listening on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9396
precaching index 'pois'
precached 1 indexes in 0.037 sec
```

Then I need to user **another server** for Rails to use this `pois` index

So I set my config like this:

```
  enable_star: true
  min_infix_len: 2
  max_matches: 10000
  version: '2.2.11'

  address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  port: 9396
```

And yes i double checked with telnet, port is open on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9396

Then I have a simple model like this:

```
  include ThinkingSphinx::ActiveRecord

  define_index "pois", with: :active_record do
    indexes name
    has latitude, longitude, population, altitude
  end
end
```

I also tried with this syntax: `sphinx_scope(:source => :pois)`

But whenever I try to make a search, I have this error sent:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ThinkingSphinx::NoIndicesError (ThinkingSphinx::NoIndicesError)
```

What do I miss?

thanks a lot

Comment: You're using TS version 2?

Comment: Gem installed is set as `thinking-sphinx (5.5.1)` and `Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to use Thinking Sphinx to integrate Sphinx with Rails, then instead of invoking `searchd` (and `indexer` and other Sphinx CLI executables) directly, you need to use Thinking Sphinx's rake tasks, such as `bundle exec rake ts:index` and `bundle exec rake ts:rebuild`:
https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v5/rake_tasks.html

But also, as noted by @smathy in a comment: the `define_index` call within a model is a *very* old syntax, not used since Thinking Sphinx v2 (2013), whereas since v3 the index definitions live in their own files in app/indices:
https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v5/indexing

Thinking Sphinx v2 is for Rails 3.0/3.1 - if you're on a newer version of Rails, then you *must* use TS v3 or newer (ideally v5.5, which supports Rails 4.2 onwards).

Comment: Thanks Pat, but my Sphinx server is not the same server where Rails run. Then on server where `searchd` is running, I already created index. Do I still need to use rake?

Comment: To make it clear, our Sphinx Daemon (also known as `searchd`) is running on a different machine, and index were built

Comment: The recommended approach in this case is to have a copy of the Rails app on both machines, and invoke the rake tasks on the server where Sphinx is.

Comment: We need to separate software environments, it's strange that we can't query Sphinx remotely with Rails. It would be nice to clearly state this in the Github or in the documentation

Comment: I'm surprised it's not covered in the docs too, I'll look to address that. Though just to be clear: you can _query_ Sphinx remotely, but you can't manage the daemon or indexer processes remotely. An alternative would be to generate the Sphinx configuration file on an app server via `rake ts:configure`, copy it to your Sphinx server, and run the Sphinx CLI commands yourself (instead of via rake) - but that's such a custom approach, hence TS not supporting it directly.